# Error declaration prototype with fancy vector

Tags: dictionary, vector, token

I have a problem, but I don't know what it is. I receive an error when I compile my code (some gnuplot is involved).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include "gnuplot_i.hpp" 

  using namespace std;

typedef struct DATA{
    char Label[50]; //title
    vector<double> y,SD; //y data point SD sigma
}DATA;

typedef map<int, double> Episode;
typedef map<int, Episode> Stat_run;

double GetAvg(double *Array, int Count, double *stddev);
void wait_for_key();
void plotMyLines(DATA *Data, vector< std::map<int, map<int, double> > > Points, int printsteps, double Y1, double Y2, int episode, int run);
void PlotLines(const char *Outfile, vector<double> x, DATA *Data, int Lines, const string &xlabel, const string &ylabel, double Y1, double Y2);


int main()
{
    vector<Stat_run> Points;
    Stat_run exp1;    Episode eps;
    Stat_run exp2;   Episode eps2;
}
```

I removed most of my code. The goal is to format some results to send them to my plotting functions. I receive an error that seems simple, but after 2 hours of test, I can't find where is my problem. Error:

```
error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘-’ token
```

I receive this error for the prototype of plotMyLines and PlotLines. Any hints appreciated!

Comment: The snippet compiles fine with gcc 4.6.1 you might want to add some compiler information. Also, why are you using a C style struct definition?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is

- not the complete minimal code to show the problem
- there is a preprocessor mess-up somewhere:

  - I can compile it no problem
  - There is not `'-' token` anywhere in this snippet of code.

**Hint** to investigate a preprocessor issue, see the output of preprocessing, e.g.

```
gcc -E -o test.cpp.ii .... (etc)
```

You should be able to see *exactly what the compiler sees* at the lines (scroll all the way down to recognize your own code).

The following compiles like a charm on g++

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef struct DATA{
    char Label[50]; //title
    vector<double> y,SD; //y data point SD sigma
}DATA;

typedef map<int, double> Episode;
typedef map<int, Episode> Stat_run;

double GetAvg(double *Array, int Count, double *stddev);
void wait_for_key();
void plotMyLines(DATA *Data, vector< std::map<int, map<int, double> > > Points, int printsteps, double Y1, double Y2, int episode, int run);
void PlotLines(const char *Outfile, vector<double> x, DATA *Data, int Lines, const string &xlabel, const string &ylabel, double Y1, double Y2);


int main()
{
    vector<Stat_run> Points;
    Stat_run exp1;    Episode eps;
    Stat_run exp2;   Episode eps2;
}
```

Comment: Except the functions plotMyLines, PlotLines and how I feed my Points vector (on which I am confident after test), there is nothing connected to this in the code.

Comment: @user1044740: the compiler is not so confident. What are you gaining by disbelieving the compiler?

Comment: Oh I don't disbelieve the compiler, he is my only friend :)

I used the command given, and found that I #define Y1 and Y2, and use them as variable name. silly me.

Comment: @user1044740: so you found the problem? I'd appreciate an accept of my answer in that case :) See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work